# Random rails ActionView::MissingTemplate errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

I've been using New Relic to track performance and have been getting a lot of errors similar to:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template layouts/templates/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:jpeg, "image/pjpeg", :png, :gif], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}. Searched in: * "/app/app/views" * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/gmaps4rails-1.5.6/app/views" * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.1.0/app/views" * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ckeditor-4.0.6/app/views" * "/app" * "/"
```

The thing is, that template at that location exists and is generally accessible. My guess is that this is perhaps due to a redirect, as I see this mostly for the home page, 404, and 500 pages.

I'm not really sure where to go with this and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Can you please share your controller name. It will be better if you share an image showing the application tree.

Comment: This happens with `PagesController#home`, `ErrorsController#show`, among others. Though those 2 seem to be the biggest offenders.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557010/missing-template-blogs-index-on-ruby-on-rails-project for possible solution to this issue.